# Adaptive neuro fuzzy inference system library

Tags: open-source, library, machine-learning

I am looking for an open source [adaptive neuro fuzzy inference system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_neuro_fuzzy_inference_system) (ANFIS) library. If possible, written in C++/Python/Java/Matlab/R and can be used on both Windows 7 and Linux.

I am aware of:

- The [MATLAB Fuzzy Logic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/index.html), which provides [some function for Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Modeling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/anfis.html).
- [NEFCLASS-J](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefclass/nefclass-j/) written in Java.

Both are closed source.

[NEFCLASS-PC and NEFCLASS-X](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefclass/) are open source but seem totally antiquated and unfinished.